# How can I display remote users cursor and selection in Quill

Tags: collaboration, quill, operational-transform

I've been working with [Quill](http://quilljs.com/) for a short time and have been focused on getting collaborative editing working. So far it's going well and I have a fully working collaborative editor!

I want to show the selection and cursor position of other users, but I can't think how to properly approach this problem with Quill.

I essentially want to add markup to the rendered document, without adding any content to the actual document model. Is this possible? Where should I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Quill 0.20, there was an [example](http://quilljs.com/0.20/examples/) with multiple cursors working. The approach was a sibling absolutely positioned `<div>` that contained the cursors and synchronized with `selection-change` information from the editor. To not delay the 1.0 release this demo and feature was not updated with the new API but support is planned. You can try a similar approach in the meantime and of course the [code](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/tree/0.20.1) is still available. You can also track the feature on [Github Issues](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/918).

Comment: Thanks, I've been using that as a starting point for an implementation. Seems to be working. Quill is awesome by the way - good job :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use "quill-cursors" package and then listen to selection-change event:

```
 editor.on("selection-change", function (range, oldRange, source) {
    console.log("Local cursor change: ", range); 
 });
```

Then broadcast this data to other remote users, and then render the remote cursor:

```
const cursors = editor.getModule("cursors");
cursors.createCursor(id, user.name, userColor);
cursors.moveCursor(id, cursorRange); // <== cursor data from previous step
cursors.toggleFlag(id, true);
```

Comment: I also spent quite a bit time on this...
I find Quill quite powerful although kind of hard to set up.